# Clarification on why my JS closure is not returning properly?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm working on a solution for Two-Sum (perhaps a bit overengineered, but it's mostly to get me comfortable with recursion and closures) and I'm trying to avoid having a counter globally if necessary. However, my function is returning undefined and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

So I wrapped my functionality (originally innerFunction was the entirety of the function and `startingIndex` was global) in an inner function, set `returnArray` to grab the base case once the recursion in `innerFunction` finishes, and return... `returnArray`. It doesn't seem to matter where I assign `returnArray` to the return value of `innerFunction`, it still isn't defined. There has to be something about the execution contexts that I'm missing and I'm sure it's obvious but I'm drawing a blank.

```js
function twoSum(numArr, target) {
  let startingIndex = 0;
  let returnArray = [];

  function innerFunction(array, integer) {
    let startNum = array.shift();
    let subtractedNum = integer - startNum;
    let found = array.findIndex(function(element) {
      return element === subtractedNum
    })

    if (found >= 0) {
      //found is the index of the shortened array
      //add 1 for the initial shift
      //add starting index, which doubles to track the amount of shifts thus far
      let endingIndex = found + 1 + startingIndex
      return [startingIndex, endingIndex];
    } else {
      startingIndex++;
      innerFunction(array, integer);
    }
  }
  returnArray = innerFunction(numArr, target)
  return returnArray;
}

console.log(twoSum([4,2,5,7,8,1,9,12,3], 15));
```

I expect, say, `twoSum([4,2,5,7,8,1,9,12,3], 15)` to output `[3,4]` as it was before I wrapped the function. What am I missing?

Comment: You code is ok, you just forgot to `return` as such `return innerFunction(array, integer);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `innerFunction` returns nothing in `else` branch, but you assigning return value from its call to a `returnArray` variable.

You must return result of recursion call too:

```
 } else {
     startingIndex++;
     return innerFunction(array, integer);
 }
```

Comment: It's a recursive call, if there's no match, you up the start point and recall innerFunction. It's not supposed to end until success.

Comment: You must return the result of recursion call too

Comment: AH I see what you mean. You're right, it works now. Thank you, I'll accept your answer in a sec. Can you give me a download of why it worked correctly before I wrapped it and not after?

Comment: @AndreaMcKenzie it is hard to inspect code without viewing it, if you add original code it be much simpler to tell

Comment: As it turns out, I made another beginner's mistake in my execution that made me think it worked when it didn't. Adding the return statement in the `else` block fixed it. Thank you again for that! If you happen to want to satisfy your curiosity for whatever reason though, it's here: https://repl.it/@siouxsieasylum/TwoSumTests

Answer (score 2):

your result is undefined because this line needs a return statement:
`innerFunction(array, integer);`

Here's a working solution:

```js
     function twoSum(position, array, integer) {
        let answer = []
        let startNum = array[position];
        let subtractedNum = integer - startNum;

        let index = -1
        for (var i = position + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
          if( array[i] === subtractedNum ) {
            index = i
          }
        }

        if (index >= 0) {
          answer = [[position, index]]
        }

        if (array.length - position > 1) {
          let theRest = twoSum(position + 1, array, integer);      
          answer = [...answer, ...theRest]
        }
        return answer
      }


    console.log(twoSum(0, [4,2,5,7,8,1,9,12,3], 15));
```

Even if you add this return statement, your solution currently is only going to return one answer unless you throw your answer onto the global accumulator (`returnArray`) or merge your answers before returning the recursive function (which is what I chose to do above).